# ProcessBuilder - Java program - Running Batch programs

Tags: java, processbuilder

I have a requirement to create one java utility so that one of the process in our team is automated. Existing process calls the executable and does business processing in sequence. I wrote a small program for this

```
    FileInputStream fstream;
    try {
        String [] cmd = new String[3];

        if(System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase().contains("win")){
            cmd[0] = "cmd.exe";
            cmd[1] = "/C";
        } else{
            cmd[0] = "/bin/sh";
            cmd[1] = "-c";
        }

        fstream = new FileInputStream("C:\\JavaProgram.txt");
         BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream));
        String FileLine,FileLine1;

          //Read File Line By Line
          while ((FileLine = br.readLine()) != null)   
          {
            cmd[2]=FileLine;  
            ProcessBuilder proc = new ProcessBuilder(cmd);
            Process p = null;

            proc.redirectErrorStream(true);
            System.out.println("Starting Process "+ FileLine);
            p = proc.start();   
            BufferedReader br1 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

             while ((FileLine1 = br1.readLine()) != null)   
              {
                 System.out.println("Output"+ FileLine1);
              } 
            int exitValue = p.waitFor();
            System.out.println("\nExit Value is " + exitValue);
          }
          br.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

The program reads the JavaProgram file which contains the list of programs to be executed in sequence. Now I have following queries:

1. The process runs in the background and to monitor, i had to check in the Task manager. Is  there any way that this process can be run foreground.
2. There are cases in which the program results in error. Is this the correct way to capture error i.e. based on `waitfor()` output. Current logic just displayed the value[which i will enhance later to display proper error message]
3. Is this the way to best way to handle this requirement[Please ignore the basic redundancy /extra processing at this point of time as it is in dev phase]
4. Some programs which it will execute will require Administrator priviledges. Does any extra code is required for that
5. Any other things to be  taken care of??

Comment: this is a good reference: http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html . As far as running app with admin priviledges, i am not sure on how to do that from java.

Comment: Please don't use DataInputStream for text.

Comment: Check out zt-exec. It's a great little library for handeling processes and comes with all your requirements.